# "String iterator not dereferncable" with boost async_read_some

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr, asio

I have a server that uses asynchronous sockets from boost with an "accept" function as follows ("User" is pretty much equivalent of "Session" in [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) example):

```
    accept()
{
    this->_acceptor.async_accept(this->_socket, [this](boost::system::error_code error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            make_shared<User>(move(_socket), *this)->read();
        }
        accept();
    });
}
```

A "read" function as follows (`_readData` is a char array of 1024):

```
    void User::read()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    this->_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(this->_readData, 1024),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code error, size_t length)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            this->buildReceivedMessage(string(this->_readData, length));
            this->read();
        }
    });
}
```

And a "write" function.

When I connect with a client to the server, the first transmission from the client to the server goes smoothly, and the server sends back a response as expected. Then, I go step by step in the code, and after the read function finishes, the code goes into several header files I do not recognize, and eventually throws a "Expression: cannot dereference string iterator because the iterator was invalidated (e.g. reallocation occurred, or the string was destroyed)" assertion problem form the `xstring` file. And for the life of me, I do not know why.

EDIT 1:
The `buildReceivedMessage` creates a `ReceivedMessage`, which contains the values of the request in an easy-to-access format, and then forwards it to a `messageHandler`, which forwards the request according to its type.
For instance, the first request is a sign in request, so `ReceivedMessage` ends up in this function:

```
void User::handleSignin(shared_ptr<ReceivedMessage> msg)
{
    vector<string> values = msg->getValues();
    if (this->_server.getDB().isUserAndPassMatch(values[0], values[1]))
    {
        if (this->getUserByName(values[0]))
        {
            this->write("1022");
        }
        else
        {
            this->_server.addUser(shared_ptr<User>(this));
            this->write("1020");
            this->_username = values[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this->write("1021");
    }
}
```

Comment: May be in the read function - print out the length and error code on receive? May be that will give you some clues?

Comment: @Nim tried to do that, output read: "system:0 (error) 16 (length of the data, which is correct)".

Comment: which compiler/boost version?

Comment: @Nim boost 1.64.0, msvc complier

Comment: The problem is not in the code you've posted, it's most likely in the code you've not posted - what happens in the `build...` method?

Comment: `void User::buildReceivedMessage(string data)
{
 shared_ptr<ReceivedMessage> msg(new ReceivedMessage(data));
 this->messageHandler(msg);
}`

Comment: The `ReceivedMessage` constructor parses the data given according to the protocol and the `messageHandler` function forwards the `ReceivedMessage` to the a handler function according to the message that was received.

Comment: For instance, the first message I'm sending from the client is a sign in request, so the `ReceivedMessage` ends up in the function I will attach to the question.

Comment: why don't you run this in gdb - and have a look at the stack trace.

Comment: I already looked at the stack trace in VS, and it led me to my main function, not even the User.cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
void User::read()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    this->_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(this->_readData, 1024),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code error, size_t length)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            this->buildReceivedMessage(string(this->_readData, length));
            this->read();
        }
    });
}
```

You are depending on shared_ptr `self` to keep your connection alive.  This is fine, but does `buildReceivedMessage()` create a shared_ptr to `self` as well?

`handleSignin()`  does not receive a shared_ptr, which makes me suspect that your object `self`, which is `this`, really is being destroyed prematurely.

I would first try to use `self` instead of `this` in `User::read()`, to ensure the capture of `self` doesn't get optimized away (yes, that is a possibility).  I'd also make sure not to rely solely on the read loop to keep the connection alive.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, some of ASIO's read/write functions takes references to mutable buffers that you provide and require that the buffer is persistent until the `async` function is complete. Using a string as a character buffer for example passing `asio::buffer(std::string("data"))` would result in this assert because the string is out of scope by the time `asio` processes the `async` function. That said, look through all your read/write functions and ensure where you pass a string as a mutable buffer, the string is persistent.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, I had this exact line and error, and ensuring the buffer didn't go out of scope until the async functions completed solved it for me.